# Switch colours when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a html code with css which displays the image 1 below (left image). What I want to accomplish is that when you hover with your mouse over image 1, I want the image 2 (Right picture) to appear (do not mind the difference in sizes).

[image: Image 1][image: Image2]

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="borderbox">
        <h3 class="header-3">+</h3>
        <p class="paragraph-text">visa fler bästsäljare</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.borderbox {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 362px; !important
    width: 241px;  !important
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 5%;      
}

h3.header-3 {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00a0df;
    margin: 4px auto 17px;
}

p.paragraph-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00a0df;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: inherit; font-weight: bold;

}
```

How can I implement this to my CSS, when you hover with your mouse over the Image 1 I want it to switch colour (image 2). The colour code for the blue is `#00a0df`.

[URL to my website](http://www.shopstuff.se/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `color: #00a0df;` to `borderbox` and change your text's color to `color: inherit`. Then on hover you can change the `background-color`,  text `color`, `border` color and anything else you want:

```
.borderbox {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 362px; !important
    width: 241px;  !important
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 5%; 
    color: #00a0df; //add
}


h3.header-3 {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    color: inherit; //change
    margin: 4px auto 17px;
}



p.paragraph-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: inherit; //change
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: inherit; font-weight: bold;

}

.borderbox:hover{
    background-color: #00a0df;
    color: #FFF;
    border-color: #FFF;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mk7hrs49/2/)

Comment: Splendid, that did the work. Is there a posibility to also change the colour of the dashed lines? Since they are still `d3d3d3` after hovering. I also want them white.

Comment: I tried your solution again and it worked but the text "Visa fler bästsäljare" is not centerd as before. How do I modify that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class, which changes the style when the mouse is hovering over the element.  Apply the colors you want (backround and font colors) to the hover attribute which will override the default (non-hovered) style.  If you put the font and background color in the `.borderbox` class, then all you need is to override these in a `.borderbox:hover` like so:

```
.borderbox:hover {
  background-color: #00a0df;
  color: white;
}
```

The full example follows:

```css
.borderbox {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: #00a0df;
    position: absolute;
    height: 362px; !important
    width: 241px;  !important
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 5%;      
}

.borderbox:hover {
  background-color: #00a0df;
  color: white;
}

h3.header-3 {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px auto 17px;
}

p.paragraph-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: inherit; font-weight: bold;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="borderbox">
        <h3 class="header-3">+</h3>
        <p class="paragraph-text">visa fler bästsäljare</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mk7hrs49/3/

In order to get the white border you want when you hover over it.

Just add border color:

```
.borderbox:hover{
    background-color: #00a0df;
    color: #FFF;
    border-color: white;  <---
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the :hover Pseudoclass. If this is new to you, check out the explanations on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com). Your code should look like that afterwards:

```
.borderbox:hover {
#Here comes all your css on hover
background-color: #00a0df;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem. :-)